# O que o comando "git branch -M main" faz?

Tags: git, github

Estou criando um novo repositório e no GitHub me da a opção de usar o comando:

```
git branch -M main
```

O que ele faz ?

Answer (score 7):

De acordo com a [documentação do comando `git branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch), a *flag* [`-M`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt--M) assume o papel de `--move` em conjunto com `--force`.

Isso significa que, ao executar o comando, a *branch* atual será renomeada para `main`, mesmo que essa *branch* já exista (efeito causado pelo `--force`).

Portanto:

```
git branch -M main
```

É o mesmo que:

```
git branch --force --move main
```

Se o nome da *branch* antes de executar o comando é, por exemplo, `master`, após a execução dele, será `main`.